# Is there a way to listen to the triggering of an event listener of a child element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say we have a parent div. Is there a way to handle the triggering of a certain event, let's say click event in this case, of any of the child elements, let's say a link () in jQuery?

Comment: You're probably looking for delegated events, but you should be clearer as to why you need this ?

Comment: Provided it's an event that *bubbles*, yes.

Comment: What if it doesn't bubble?

Comment: Then jQuery makes it bubble ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the type of event, you should be able to use either the [`click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) or [`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) events to listen for it using your preferred syntax :

```
// Pick up any click events triggered by a "child" element below a specific parent
$('.parent .child').click(function(){ ... });
```

or :

```
// Do the same thing (using .on() will pick up dynamically added elements)
$('.parent').on('click','.child',function(){ ... });
```

**Example**

You can [see a complete example of this here](http://jsbin.com/cinocuf/edit?html,output) and demonstrated below :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Sure, use `.on()` binding function:

```
$('.parent-div').on('click', '.child', function(e){
  // Your code
});
```